# Laravel project size is too large. How to deploy?

Tags: laravel

I was made easy blog on Laravel Framework and now it is finished. But I am new guy in this. So the question how to deploy my project? The Vendor and ClockWork folders has thousands of files. I think that it should not to upload to the server. Am I wrong?

Comment: vendor folder should not be actually deployed you generally run `composer install`  if you aren't able to run the command in the server then i guess you don't have any other option than zipping the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project will not work without vendor dependencies, but true - sending it all over SSH is quite long and archive will be huge - uploading them every time by yourself will be annoying. Usually, you do not upload `vendor` and `node_modules` folders to the server, but run:

```bash
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

npm install && npm run build && rm -R node_modules
```

Read more details in Laravel's [deployment](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deploymen) section

Comment: How about the clockwork folder? It has more then 3,000 json files..

Comment: I assuming you are talking about https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork. This is dev tools, you don't need that on production

Answer (score -1):

maybe try to compress the project to a zip file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).